# remove route in google maps using closeclick from infoWindow

Tags: angular, google-maps, routes, angular-material

Once I clicked the marker on the map, the route will be displayed along with the infoWindow. I want to clear my route when I close the infoWindow. Once I clicked the marker on the map, the route will be displayed along with the infoWindow. I want to clear my route when I close the infoWindow.

Already try the `directionDisplay.setMap(null)` but still the route is not cleared.

This is my listener. I dont know if the closeClick function is correct.

```
let directionsDisplay = new window['google'].maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        suppressMarkers: true,
        preserveViewport: true,
      });

let directionsService = new window['google'].maps.DirectionsService();
```

```
marker.addListener('click', () => {
        let infoWindowContent =
          '<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=' +
          encodeURI(this.camelize(this.hospitals[i].facilityName)) +
          '" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong>' +
          this.camelize(this.hospitals[i].facilityName) +

        let infoWindow = new window['google'].maps.InfoWindow({
          content: infoWindowContent,
        });

        infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);

       //This is where I suppose to clear the route, during infoWindow closed
        marker.addListener(infoWindow, 'closeclick', function() {
          directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
          directionsDisplay = null;

        });

        directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

        if (this.hospitals[i].facilityCode !== this.hospitals[i].leadFacilityCode) {
          let request = {
            origin: new window['google'].maps.LatLng(
              Number(this.hospitals[i].latitude),
              Number(this.hospitals[i].longitude)
            ),
            destination: new window['google'].maps.LatLng(
              Number(this.hospitals[i].leadFacilityLatitude),
              Number(this.hospitals[i].leadFacilityLongitude)
            ),
            travelMode: window['google'].maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          };

          
          directionsService.route(request, (result: any, status: any) => {
            if (status === 'OK') {

              directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);

            }
          
          });
        }
      
      });
```

Comment: You are using angular to display it? Are you using OnPush change detection or default?

Comment: Yes, Im using angular to display it

Comment: Does your `marker.addListener(infoWindow,...` method runs.. when you click close the infowindow?  Have you tried this : `directionsDisplay.setMap('directions', null);`

Comment: Yes, it does close the infoWindow, but the route is still not cleared. I tried the ``directionsDisplay.setMap('directions', null);`` still the same

Answer (score 0):

I just add this.

`infoWindow.addListener('closeclick', () =>{ directionsDisplay.setMap(null); directionsDisplay.setDirections(null); })`